# Can A Chrome Extension Detect a URL Only Once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the following code to detect if the user is about to visit a particular site.

```
var array = ["foo.bar", "foo.com", "foo.org"];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (id, info, tab) {
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(array[i]) != -1) {

            chrome.notifications.create('main', {
                type: 'basic',
                iconUrl: 'icon.png',
                title: 'Title Message',
                message: 'Message Body'
        }, function(notificationId) {});
    }
}});
```

The problem is that it runs everytime the user navigations *within* `foo.com` for example.  Is there a way to detect that URL only once, and stop it from displaying the notification everytime a link within the site is clicked?
I'm new to javascript and Chrome Extension APIs so hopefully I can follow along.

EDIT - to clarify the question, I would like it to detect the URL only once while the user is on the page.  But if they navigate to another page, it would then detect that URL again.  For example, user goes to foo.com and the notification is shown.  The user navigates around the page and the notification is not tripped for these navigations.  User goes to google.com then back to foo.com and the notification is shown again.

Comment: too broad. read the basics of storage and background scripts in extension official docs.

Comment: Only once per.. what? Day? Browsing session until restart? Lifetime of the extension?

Comment: @Xan I've added an edit to the question.

Comment: What about navigation in several tabs?

Comment: @Xan I think it's ok to focus on a single tab.  If user wants to open foo.com in multiple tabs, then it's ok for notification to be shown for each.  But within the tab I only want the notification to be shown once unless they navigate away from foo.com and back again.

Answer (score 0):

So your requirement is:

- When the user first navigates to a site in question, show the notification
- As long as the user navigates within that site, do not do anything
- If the user navigates away (for a particular tab), "rearm" the mechanism

So basically, what we take away from that is that you need to store 1 bit worth of information ("armed"/"disarmed") *per tab* (or specifically, per tab ID). You do not need persistence between browser session, so just a persistent background page is enough (if you want to use event pages, you'll need `chrome.storage`, but it's out of scope of the answer).

Here's an example, keeping with "alarm"/"trap" terminology:

```
var disarmed = {}; // Will contain tab IDs that are disarmed
                   // disarmed[tabId] is false by default

var hosts = ["foo.bar", "foo.com", "foo.org"];

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (id, info, tab) {
  var trigger = false; // Determines if our condition is met

  hosts.forEach(function(hostname) {
    // Note: this is a bad condition - will trigger on http://example.com/?q=foo.com
    // But that's for you to fix
    if (tab.url.indexOf(hostname) != -1) {
      trigger = true;
    }
  });

  if (trigger) {
    // Condition satisfied, see if we need to notify
    if (!disarmed[tab.id]) {
      notify(tab); // You may want to know the URL in notify()
      disarmed[tab.id] = true;
    }
  } else {
    // Condition no longer satisfied, rearm
    disarmed[tab.id] = false;
  }
});

function notify(tab) {
  chrome.notifications.create('main', {
    type: 'basic',
    iconUrl: 'icon.png',
    title: 'Title Message',
    message: 'Message Body'
  }, function(notificationId) {});
}
```

A little concern here is that over time, `disarmed` will grow in size. With only one value per tab ID it's unlikely to grow *much*, but you can clear entries in it (`delete disarmed[tabId]`) when a tab gets removed (`onRemoved`) or replaced (`onReplaced` - you need to watch that too for changes).

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution.  I've noticed that it doesn't get called everytime and I've found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21227525/2018846) which I imagine is occurring.  I added `if (info.status == "complete") { //arm/disarm code }` but it still doesn't seem to work 100% of the time.  Any idea's of what could be occurring?

Comment: Likely you have to watch `onReplaced` as well. Or, actually, consider using `webNavigation` API.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I've kind of figured out that it doesn't matter if notification is created on first page load.  It'll usually be caught on the second page (first nav within google.com) and that's ok for what I need.  Thanks again though!  Much appreciated.